# If variable is within range of another variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, syntax

I have a loop that updates when GPS coordinates change at the third decimal by comparing previous coordinates with current coordinates every 10 minutes.

However, I would only like for the updates to happen if the decimal changes by more than +/- 0.002. Meaning, if $latA = 64.019 or $lonA = -152.617 and $latB = 64.017, 64.018, 64.020, or 64.021; or $lonB = -152.615, -152.616, -152.618, or -152.619; then I would like the if statement to read true.

```
while :
do
    LAT=$(cat /tmp/getGPS | awk 'BEGIN{RS=","; FS=":"} /lat/ {save=$2} END {print save}')
    LON=$(cat /tmp/getGPS | awk 'BEGIN{RS=","; FS=":"} /lon/ {save=$2} END {print save}')
    ALT=$(cat /tmp/getGPS | awk 'BEGIN{RS=","; FS=":"} /alt/ {save=$2} END {print save}')
    ALT=$(echo "scale=0; $ALT * 3.281/1" | bc)
    latB=$(echo "scale=3; $LAT /1" | bc)
    lonB=$(echo "scale=3; $LON /1" | bc)
  if [ "$latA" = "$latB" ] || [ "$lonA" = "$lonB" ]
    then
      echo "latA = latB"
      sleep 600
    else
      echo "latA != latB"
      latA=$latB
      lonA=$lonB
  fi
done
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ ./getGPS
0 - 64.019123167 -152.617497833 114ft
A -
B - 64.019 -152.617
latA != latB
0 - 64.019124167 -152.617497667 115ft
A - 64.019 -152.617
B - 64.019 -152.617
latA = latB
Sleeping...
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to use `bc` for this:

```
$ epsilon="0.002"
$ echo "define abs(i) {if (i < 0) return (-i); return (i)}; abs(64.019 - 64.018) <= $epsilon" | bc
1
$ echo "define abs(i) {if (i < 0) return (-i); return (i)}; abs(64.019 - 64.016) <= $epsilon" | bc
0
```

This bc script returns 0 (false) if the difference is greater than `epsilon`, 1 (true) otherwise.

You can use it like so:

```
latNearlyEqual=$(echo "define abs(i) {if (i < 0) return (-i); return (i)}; abs($latA - $latB) <= $epsilon" | bc)
if [ $latNearlyEqual -eq 1 ]
then
    ...
fi
```